# tfs $tf folder is missing from local workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to integrate our TFS with an external tool (Sonar) and for this Sonar needs the $tf folder that is supposedly (according to MS documentation) is supposed to exist on local workspaces.
I actually never seen this folder in any local environment before.
why am I not seeing this folder?
how can I have TFS/VS create it?

a few notes:

1. I looked for hidden files.
2. using VS 2010 premium / VS2013 premium and TFS2010

Comment: Note that a "local workspace" is an explicit type of workspace where the metadata is kept local.  You can also have a "server workspace" configured with workspace mappings on your workstation.  It's confusing terminology, I admit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS and VS2010 don't support local workspaces. You'll need to upgrade both to at least 2012 (ideally, 2013) in order to use them.

Comment: Thank you (all) very much, I see my problem now. since we are working with TFS2010 I wasn't even aware of any of that.